# Apache Server Alias Dirname Has Dot

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp, alias

I want create server alias for laravel in apache Xampp
But when the dirname has (.) dot when i access the url returned 404 not found

Here my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 UseCanonicalName Off

 ServerAlias *.learning.local
 VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Framework/Laravel/Learning/%1/public" 
</VirtualHost>
```

I have sub folder like this

```
 - Laravel
 - - Learning
 - - - laravel-7.x
 - - - laravel-7.x-oauth-client
```

And on hosts file i setup like this :

```
127.0.0.1 laravel-7.x.learning.local
127.0.0.1 laravel-7.x-oauth-client.learning.local
```

When i access url like this `http://laravel-7.x.learning.local/` returned 404 not found